# AS3: Taking screenshot for a 3D object

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d

I want to take a screenshot for a 3d object, 
I tried the following:

```
var screenshot:BitmapData = new BitmapData(ViewerWidth, ViewerHeight);
screenshot.draw(Viewer3D); 
var imageTaken:Bitmap = new Bitmap(screenshot); 
addChild(imageTaken);
```

but it is not working for 3d objects!

How can I do it or how to draw a 3D object to a Bitmap Data?
Thanks.

Comment: what 3d library are you using?

Comment: i'm not creating the 3d object, i got it from an external library and add it to my stage.
mainly it is a context3d.

Comment: see [this thread](http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/screenshot-via-context3ddrawtobitmapdata)

Comment: thank you George,
but the problem is that i can't access the methods where the context3d is drawn, it is i a library and i am just adding it to my stage.

Comment: add code where you initialised the Viewer3D